# Why is the foreign key not accepted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, constraints

Why is the table `Room` not accepting the foreign key?

```
CREATE TABLE RoomType (
Roomtype nvarchar(2) NOT NULL,
Description nvarchar(20),
Responsibility nvarchar(20),
primary key (Roomtype)
)

Create table Room (
RoomID nvarchar(2) NOT NULL,
Capacity numeric(3)
)
ALTER TABLE Room 
add foreign key(Roomtype)
references RoomType(Roomtype)
```

This is the error message I get when I run alter table.

> Major Error 0x80040E11, Minor Error 0
>   ALTER TABLE Room 
>   add foreign key(Roomtype)
>   references RoomType(Roomtype)
>   Invalid column ID. [ Roomtype ]

Comment: Just added it on now. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you want to reference an existing field in the Room table when adding your foreign key? Adding a foreign key constraint does not add the field.

Comment: What @MartinSoles soles mean, you need `Roomtype` field in your `Room` table

Comment: That is correct. But isnt that what alter is for?

Comment: @salmanabedin You first need `ALTER TABLE Room ADD COLUMN Roomtype nvarchar(2);`

Comment: why are your ID values `nvarchar` and not `int`? it's bad design that you should fix.

Comment: Ill give that a try. Thanks. I am new to sql.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking too but on the tutorial sheet thats what the id type has to be apparently. @Tanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the foreign key as a field to the Room table before you attempt to declare the foreign key constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE RoomType (
Roomtype nvarchar(2) NOT NULL,
Description nvarchar(20),
Responsibility nvarchar(20),
primary key (Roomtype)
)

Create table Room (
RoomID nvarchar(2) NOT NULL,
Capacity numeric(3)
)

ALTER TABLE Room
ADD Roomtype nvarchar(2) NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE Room 
add constraint FK_Give_Me_A_Good_Name foreign key(Roomtype)
references RoomType(Roomtype)
```

Answer (score 0):

The column must exist BEFORE you can FK to it.

```
CREATE TABLE RoomType (
Roomtype nvarchar(2) NOT NULL,
Description nvarchar(20),
Responsibility nvarchar(20),
primary key (Roomtype)
)

Create table Room (
RoomID nvarchar(2) NOT NULL,
Capacity numeric(3),
RoomtypeA nvarchar(2) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Room] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MyName FOREIGN KEY (RoomtypeA) REFERENCES dbo.Roomtype (Roomtype) 
GO
```

Comment: Note, I made it "RoomTypeA" simply to avoid ambiguity, you don't need to name it like this.